# How to set view for only one group, even if other group inherits from this group?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I work with Odoo 8.
I have 2 classes: A and B, B inherits from A.
I want to have a view only for A group.
I can make a menu item for group A but then, it is visible for group B too.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can not block higher groups to visible base group's entity.

```
        <record model="res.groups" id="group_user_ept">
            <field name="name">User</field>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/> 
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>                       
        </record>

        <record model="res.groups" id="group_manager_ept">
            <field name="name">Manager</field>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/> 
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_user_ept'))]"/>                       
        </record>

        <record model="res.groups" id="group_additional_ept">
            <field name="name">Additional Group</field>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/> 
        </record>
```

Create one more group and set two groups together. And allow the new group to base user only not to the higher level group's users.

> By applying more than one groups you can prevent to other group
>   members to visible it's own entity. Or you can also remove relation
>   between the group then you don't need to manage this.